# Is there a better way to share Python modules and manage dependencies?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and walking through a course-book. Currently I am learning how to share a python lib across multiple projects by installing it in site-packages.

I learned that one needs to follow below steps

1. Create a setup.py which will help in creating distribution using setup tools.
2. Create the distribution by running the setup.py file created above.
3. In other project install the distribution using pip install command.
4. Then the other project shall be able to use the modules of the lib installed.

Can the above steps be done in fewer steps like is there any plugin or framework which can reduce this further. I am asking because I am relatively new to Python so I am suspecting that this could be the most basic approach.

Comment: It only seems like a lot of work because you're unfamiliar with it. With Maven you have to install Maven (it doesn't come with Java), run a project setup command that will generate a pom.xml (analogous to setup.py), `mvn compile` (analogous to running setup.py), and in the other project install the package (or at least put a JAR file somewhere specific). That's not any less work. To be honest, your question comes across as more of a rant about the difficulty of doing something that you haven't actually tried yet.

Comment: Regardless, a question of this sort is explicitly off topic; we don't do recommendations for alternate third-party libraries because judging them is considered too subjective. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: What would you consider as "better" and "easier"? What problems do you have with the current approach? It also depends on what "multiple projects" mean, for ex. if it's just your own projects that only you work on your own PC. See the other answers here for alternatives to creating a distribution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1819326/2745495

Comment: In my opinion, you are doing it well. It is good to be able to write simple `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` respectively. It has to contain only a few lines to be fully functional. On the other hand, if you want to be able to quickly set up the whole project you can use some project generator such as [coockiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter)

Comment: I am afraid I broke the policy / rules but my intention of asking was very simple. I just needed to understand are there any easier steps to do above Yes/No? But I understand now that it will lead to discussion of different plugins / tools which is against stackoverflow's policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to simply python packaging and dependency managment. Poetry manages the package dependencies and automates the publishing process.

Comment: Using poetry just simplifies step 1. You still have to do the remaining steps: create a distribution and install the distribution on the other project. The question is about distributing your modules and letting other projects `pip install` your package.